# ical integration for apple devices through ruby on rails

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

Hi after a lot of research in web i could not find any gem for integrating apple devices icalendar or ical with ruby on rails applications.

I have seen for apple devices there is a 'webcal subscription link' how can i create a webcal url in ruby on rails and how to create a subscription calendar for apple devices from ruby on rails app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish between event-links (.ics files or links) and CalDAV feeds (calender sync).
See [this PDF](http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920032717/Syncing_Calendar_with_ICS_Files.pdf) for explanation.

To generate .ics entries (RFC2445), there are some gems. i.e.:

- [icalendar](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar)
- [ri_cal](https://github.com/rubyredrick/ri_cal)

with these gems, you can generate ICS content and link to it. The iOS-Device will generate a new calender entry when you click such a link.

It is possible to create files with many calender entries and Calender can "subscribe" this, similar to an RSS feed, whith the URL scheme `webcal`. I use i.e.:

> webcal://ifeiertage.de/by-.ics

CalDAV on the other hand needs a calender server like DaviCAL, owncloud (or Google Calender) with authentication. As far as I know (see PFD above) there is no easy way to generate such an account with a single link.
You would have to create a Configuration Profile for iOS.

Answer (score -1):

You can access iOS inbuilt apps like this

If you're looking for the URL Schema, iPhone Calendar is:

```
<a href="CALSHOW://something here?">Click me!</a>
```

More can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html).

If above doesn't work, you may look at this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004775-SW1)

Hope it helps!